# How do I block rows/columns/cells from certain users on the shared Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with sensitive data. How might I block a certain column from others users viewing it?

Comment: See this answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24277522/

Comment: Add more details. I.E. explain if the non-sensitive data is required for calculations of the sensitive data or vice versa.

Comment: you can create object that will cover sensitive data and which will looks like background (empty cells)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Now is possible to block viewers to make a copy or download a shared spreadsheet. For details see [Stop, limit or change sharing](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2494893?hl=en).

---

There is no way to securely block <strike>viewers or</strike> editors from getting viewing access to a range of cells. I.E. anyone having access to a spreadsheet **as editor** could create a copy, this will make the copy creator the owner of it.

One alternative **for editors** is to use two spreadsheets, one for sensitive data and another for non-sensitive data each of them with the proper access permissions.

NOTE: I'm working on an spreadsheet add-on that I hope to be able to release during September 2018.